# Tactics to beat pioneer rush?

Tags: company-of-heroes

The German pioneer rush can be very effective especially against the Brits. What tactics can you use as Brit or American to defeat this move?

Comment: This question is outdated, pioneer rush does not work anymore due german engineers receive massive debuffs if blobbed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bren Carriers can deal with pioneers very well.
Just stay cool and have your tommies bail out of cover when the flamethrowers start.
Having a mortar pit ready to go near your hq truck can really put the beat down on Pioneers.

Don't forget pioneers are an engineer unit, not a shock troop. Just cut them down.

Answer (score 1):

Cut off their supply lines, the main advantage of pio spam is just to grab as much territory as possible.

As the above poster said, keep your Tommies in green cover. But watch out, once the pioneers get flame throwers you're toast if you're in green cover.

Answer (score 0):

Shoot at them?  I haven't ever seen Pioneer rushing be a viable tactic.  Just build infantry, and be ready for them.  It takes time for them to reach you, so use that time to setup your men behind cover and ambush them when they arrive.